# 2 way coupling of generics in java

Tags: java, generics

sorry about the title I couldn't explain it in one sentence better!

so here is the problem, I'm making a small Card games engine in java, I'm trying to define the interfaces for the games to be as generic as possible

so I have these interfaces

```
public interface Card
{
     //some methods
}
public interface CardGame<TCard extends Card,TPlayer extends Player>
{
     //example method
     TPlayer getPlayerByName(String name);
}
public interface Player<TCardGame extends CardGame>
{
     //HERE IS THE ISSUE
     List<TCard> getCards();
}
```

the issue is in the last interface, I want to force a player to return the same type of cards of the game that is he is a generic of

in other words, `Player<BannaCardGame>` , should have `List<BananCards>`

but I can't find the right syntax to do this, TCard inside the Player interface has no meaning

so how can I achieve this behaviour ?

Comment: First of all, don't use raw types.

Comment: will you sure like to keep an air of mystery about your self :P, I'm not sure I'm following, but thanks for the comment

Comment: `TCardGame extends CardGame` uses the raw (=unparameterized) type `CardGame`. Don't do that, it's not safe.

Comment: yeah I know this, this just an example I typed the code here in stackoverflow not from my IDE, I was just trying to figure out how to bring the context of card to the player class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might want to rethink whether you really need that. But not knowing why you might need it etc. here's some advice on how you could tackle your question:

Don't tie `Player` to `CardGame` but tie both to `Card`:

```
public interface Card {}

public interface CardGame<TCard extends Card,TPlayer extends Player<TCard>> {
 //example method
 TPlayer getPlayerByName(String name);
}

public interface Player<TCard extends Card> {     
 List<TCard> getCards();
}
```

Now you're only allowed to define a `CardGame` that uses matching implementations of `Player` and `Card`.

But again, I'm not sure that design is good (why should a player instance depend on the type of cards?) but since we don't know your requirements and why you decided to design it that way it's hard to give much advice on that (and it might be out of scope for SO anyways) so I'll leave this for you.

Edit:

From your comments it seems you also want to add `getGame()` to your `Player` interface (note for future questions: add that to the question as well, otherwise it might be missed).

You could define that method like this (I'll include the interface for completeness):

```
public interface Player<TCard extends Card> {     
  List<TCard> getCards();

  CardGame<TCard, ? extends Player<TCard>> getGame();
}
```

This would mean the player can return (belong to?) any game that uses the right type of card and any type of player declared for that type of card.

If you want to further restrict this, you could extend your interfaces (maybe that's what you're actually after):

```
//for the changes on TPlayer see the comment on Player
public interface CardGame<TCard extends Card,TPlayer extends Player<TCard, TPlayer>> {
  //example method
  TPlayer getPlayerByName(String name);
}

//Require the implementations to register themselves as generic types
public interface Player<TCard extends Card, TPlayer extends Player<TCard, TPlayer>> {     
  List<TCard> getCards();

  CardGame<TCard, TPlayer> getGame();
}
```

A `BananaCard` game could then look like this:

```
class BananaPlayer implements Player<BananaCard, BananaPlayer> {
  public List<BananaCard> getCards() { /*snip*/ }

  public CardGame<BananaCard, BananaPlayer> getGame() { /*snip*/ } 
}

class BananaGame implements CardGame<BananaCard, BananaPlayer> {
  public BananaPlayer getPlayerByName( String pName ) { /*snip*/ }    
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking about the design part
Initially nothing was generic, but the deeper I go the worse it gets, a player should have strong type of the game he is in not just CardGame, so I ended up overriding the getGame methods in each subclass to return the same type! this isn't even allowed in c# for example, so I back tracked and started using generics

as for the other issue I agree, that's why a player is a generic of its game not the card in my design, but how can I force the type of card of that game on the player!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last sentence (a question?) but you could do it like this: `BananaCard extends Card`, `BananaPlayer extends Player<BananaCard>`, `BananaCardGame extends CardGame<BananaCard, BananaPlayer >` (`CardGame<AppleCard, BananaPlayer>` wouldn't be allowed).

Comment: I tried this, I mean the most obvious way is to include the generic of card inside the player definition, but as you said this looks bad and confusing, a player should not be tied to a card definition, it should be tied to a game definition, and at the same time that game is a generic of some card, but I can't use that card in the player interface context

Comment: No, I don't find it confusing that way. What I find confusing is that the player is tied to a certain game definition but if it needs to be that way then the player can as well be tied to the type of card used in that game. Besides that I'm not sure that tying a player to a game is something that can/should be ensured at compile time but as already said I don't know your requirements and other design decisions that lead to this.

Comment: ok, if I ignored the cards problem for now, why shouldn't the player be tied to a game? how do you usually achieve player.getGame() to get a strong type of that game?

Comment: @HassanKhallouf I've added a rather lengthy edit and hope that helps.

Comment: thanks Thomas, this is really helpful, not sure if I want to complicate the design this much or find a better way but this sure answers the question.

Comment: @HassanKhallouf yes it can get rather complicated, that's why I suggested rethinking the design. Doing it that way is quite helpful but can get out of hand so it's often better to take a step back and check the overall design. Good luck with that. :)